# Highlight bash internal varibles using VIM

Tags: bash, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to Highlight bash internal varibles using VIM?

For example the variables described on this page would appear a different colour than the user defined variables.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define additional syntax keywords for those built-in variables. Put the following into `~/.vim/after/syntax/sh.vim`:

```
syntax keyword shBuiltInVariable BASH BASH_ENV BASH_VERSION containedin=shDerefSimple
highlight def link shBuiltInVariable Special
```

The `containedin=` is necessary because shell variables are already parsed by existing syntax groups, and these additional overrides need to go in there to match.

Also note that `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/sh.vim` supports multiple shell dialects; if you use different shells, you need to add proper conditionals (`b:is_bash` etc.) around your additions.